# Will the database connection be open if the calling server is rebooted

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, windows-services

This is an interesting scenario to which I'm getting conflicting answers.

I have a web page or service on a server that initiates a db call to a database stored procedure on a different server that say runs for about 20 hours, after which the control is passed back to the calling server.

Now for some reason the server that initiates the db call is restarted after the DB call has been made, will that close the db process running the stored procedure? or will it wait for the stored procedure to complete its work before its closed?

For specifics, I'm planning to design a windows service that opens a connection to the oracle database and runs the stored procedure and then closes it once its completed.

I'm just curious as to how that would work.

Comment: That is just a bad design.  use DBMS_SCHEDULER to kick off the procedure, and post the results somewhere and query the scheduler tables for completion.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I'm just talking about a scenario. what would happen to the procedure execution if the call initiating server is rebooted?

Comment: So try a test and see.